# Error running npx create-strapi-starter my-project gatsby-blog

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I was following Strapi's [Quick Start Guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html) where you can use a starter to  create a project with Gatsby by running:

```
npx create-strapi-starter my-project gatsby-blog
```

The backend part installed all dependencies, but the frontend part failed with this message:

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-markdown@4.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-markdown
npm ERR!   react-markdown@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/ronald/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

I'm using a Mac with Node v14.17.1 and NPM 7.24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install the peer dependencies due some mismatching between versions.

For example, React needs to be between `^15.0.0` and `^16.0.0` and found a `17.0.2`:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
```

Try downgrading each version to the corresponding one or just run the command using the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. On the root of the front-end project just run:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

You can even try it with the original command:

```
npx create-strapi-starter my-project gatsby-blog
```

Comment: I changed react and react-dom to ^16.0.0 and run npm i, but I got another "ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree" error. Then I run it with --legacy-peer-deps "to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution." and it made the trick. But then starting the backend part I got more errors, so I'm dropping this now. Thanks anyway!